# make a for loop in a loop that doesnt count the first thing of the loop again

Tags: python

hey guys im building a blackjack game and i want to make it so that in the first round you get 2 cards instead of one see code:

```
import random

deckTypes = []
    cardType = ["Spade", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"]
    cardValues = ["Ace", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "J", "Q", "K"]
    Values = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
    for i in cardType:
        for j in cardValues:
            deckTypes.append(str(j) + " of " + str(i))

deck = dict(zip(deckTypes, Values*4))
playerValue = []
playerHand = []

  def drawPlayerCard():
        card = random.choice(list(deck))
        playerHand.append(card)
        print(playerHand)

        for p in playerHand:
            playerValue.append(deck[p])
            print(playerValue)

        print("Your Cards are:", playerHand)
        print("total value of:", sum(playerValue), "\n")

        if len(playerHand) < 2:
            drawPlayerCard()
        else:
            pass


drawPlayerCard()
```

but when i do this i get the first number 2 times. i know why this is its because the code loops through the for loop 2 times but how can i change this so that i get the first and the second without 2 times getting the first.

outcome:

```
Your Cards are: ['3 of Clubs']
total value of: 3 

['3 of Clubs', 'J of Diamonds']
[3, 3]
[3, 3, 10]
Your Cards are: ['3 of Clubs', 'J of Diamonds']
total value of: 16
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve]

Comment: This isn't your problem, but your code doesn't seem to ever remove a card from the deck after it's been dealt, so the same card can be dealt multiple times.

Comment: @kindall That is exactly the problem.

Comment: @kindall i know this and im very new to python and programming in general so i first want to make a version that works and what i understand before moving unto the next bit of the program

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's happening:

The code picks a card and puts it in your hand, so we get:

```
Hand: X

Value:
```

Then it gets the value for that card, so now we have:

```
Hand: X 

Value: X1
```

Now, the function is called again because we have less than two cards, so we add another card.

```
Hand: X, Y

Value: X1
```

But notice how you get your card values, you iterate through the Hand and get the value. So if we were to do that with our hand of X, Y we would get:

```
X1, Y1
```

However, we already have X1 in our list! So, what do we end up with?

```
Value: (X1 added by the first function call), (X1, Y1 added by the second function call)
```

What you need to do to fix this problem (granted, there are many possible solutions, this is only one) is to *separate the logic of drawing a card and calculating its value*. What I suggest is to create a second function which takes in the input of a player's hand and generates your sum.